# Do CentOS RPMs work with RedHat?

Tags: rpm

I am having trouble finding certain Redhat EL5 RPMs but there are a lot of CentOS versions out there. Would they work or are they completely incompatible with RedHat even though they have "el5" in the name?

Comment: CentOS is derived from RedHat!

Comment: Not sure whether Unix & Linux SE existed back in 2010, but it seems like the appropriate place to find this question...not Superuser.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, CentOS is for all intents and purposes an exact copy of RHEL.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed they do as Martin outlined. If you're having trouble finding packages for Redhat, use [**RPMForge**](http://rpmrepo.org/RPMforge). They maintain a massive package repository for Redhat, RHEL, Fedora, and CentOS users.

Answer (score 0):

If you need extra packages (which is what you seem to be looking for) than the first thing to consider using is [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) (Extra Package For Enterprise Linux). If you still can't find what you are looking for then load rpmfusion or rpmforge repo for the appropriate Redhat release. One thing to note is that RH will not support you if you break your system.

Comment: @Zigster you have three answers, please pick one.